# What are some big brand Dunkel beers in the United States?

Tags: german-beers, lager, distribution, united-states, retail-availiability

I love Dunkel's (German Dark Lager) every time I have them but live in a small town without much local access to imported or small brewery beers (unless they are a bigger name). What I want to know is what are some brands of Dunkel that are more common with distributors that I may be able to get a local retailer to stock or order?

Answer (score 3):

**What are some big brand Dunkel beers in the United States?**

First of all what are Dunkels?

> Dunkel is the German word meaning dark, and dunkel beers typically range in color from amber to dark reddish brown. They are characterized by their smooth malty flavor. In informal terms, such as when ordering at a bar, "dunkel" is likely to mean whatever dark beer the bar has on tap, or sells most of; in much of north and western Germany, especially near Düsseldorf, this may be Altbier. - [Dunkel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunkel)

Depending on where you live you may be able to find some big brand name Dunkels. In Washington state I generally go to BevMo, in Bellingham.  They usually have most varieties of everything that is available.

They have in stock [Warsteiner Dunkel](https://www.bevmo.com/shop/beer_and_hard_seltzer/imported_beers/specialty_beer/warsteiner_dunkel_6_pkb_12_oz/p/1564405684704481797) and [Erdinger Dunkel](https://www.bevmo.com/shop/beer_and_hard_seltzer/imported_beers/erdinger_dunkel_6_pkb_11_2_oz/p/1564405684704504516), [Hofbrau Dunkel](https://www.bevmo.com/shop/beer_and_hard_seltzer/imported_beers/dark_lager/hofbrau_dunkel_6_pkb_12_oz/p/1564405684704488160), [Weihenstephaner Hefeweissbier Dunke](https://www.bevmo.com/shop/beer_and_hard_seltzer/imported_beers/dark_lager/weihenstephaner_hefeweissbier_dunkel_16_9_oz_btl/p/1564405684704477662), [Ayinger Altabairisch Dunkel](https://www.bevmo.com/shop/beer_and_hard_seltzer/imported_beers/specialty_beer/ayinger_altabairisch_dunkel_16_9_oz_btl/p/1564405684704471433) and [Weltenburger Barock Dunkel](https://www.bevmo.com/shop/beer_and_hard_seltzer/imported_beers/dark_lager/weltenburger_barock_dunkel_16_9_oz_btl/p/1564405684704499888).

Occasionally, they are out of stock, but then so are other outlets. Check around and you will be able to locate some Dunkles here or there. The bigger outlets are best to deal with.

If BevMo is unable to obtain a certain variety, look elsewhere. They are in several different states.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sam Adams Dunkel Lager
2. Spaten Munich Dunkel
3. Ayinger Altbairisch Dunkel
4. Paulaner Munich Dunkel
5. Weihenstephaner Original Dunkel
6. Hacker-Pschorr Munich Dark
7. Hofbräu München Dunkel
8. Warsteiner Premium Verum Dunkel
9. Sierra Nevada Tumbler Autumn Brown Ale
10. Bell's Brewery Kalamazoo Stout